# Extract string between = and ,

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the following string

```
DEA=R,SL=R,CLIA=O,JCAHO=O
```

I have to extract the string between `=` and `,`

I need `R,R,O,O`

Please suggest me the query.

Comment: What have you tried? Probably nothing, I know, but I still have to ask because we like to see some effort from the one asking.

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to do this.

Assuming your string comes from column `col1` on table `t1` ...

```
select regexp_replace(col1 
                       , '([A-Z]+)=([A-Z],?)'
                       , '\2' ) as extr_str
from t1;
```

This solution is tightly coupled to the format of the posted string: series of letters followed by equals sign followed by single letter optionally followed by comma. You will need to adjust the search pattern to reflect variations in your real data.

Comment: that's a long regex i guess.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja - It's a very exact regex. The OP has provided us with no guidance regarding strings they **don't** want to match.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach as it should be as below with REGEXP_REPLACE(...) meaning all those characters and any number of(Alphabets A-Z) which are before `=` replace them blank space giving the desired output

```
 select  REGEXP_REPLACE(
          'DEA=R,SL=R,CLIA=O,JCAHO=O','[A-Z]*=','')
             from dual;
```

[image]

Comment: Won't this fail for the last value, `JCAHO=O`?

Comment: Never mind my earlier comment, this answer doesn't work at all.

Comment: well, even i thought of using `regex_replace ` first  but that will not have any impact and using `INSTR(...)` to get whether be the last index with (-1 be the starting index in INSTR)  or the first index it will work for only 1 such pattern (above one) not for all. What we actually need is to split with `,` and then INSTR(..)

Comment: But why post an answer that doesn't work?

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: Have you checked yourself?

Comment: Yes of course, it works

Answer (score 0):

Use Oracle regular expressions

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( value, '\w+=', '' );
```

This regex will remove words that are on the left side of the equal sign. It is simpler than all other answers and will perform just as fine.

Comment: why to remove words which are on right side of the equal sign instead the OP wants those

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja : that was a typo in my answer (but the regexp was OK), fixed it... Thanks !